# Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: while trying to return reader

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to return a reader so I can read from it in another class. And when I'm calling this: return cmd.ExecuteReader(); I get a Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: The same thing happens when I'm for example try to call a insert query and call cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
I have the following classes:

Database.cs:

```
public class Database
    {
    private SqliteConnection connection;
    public string connectiondata;
    private static string _LocalDatabasePath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "LocalData.db3");

    public Database(string ConnectionString)
    {
        this.connection = new SqliteConnection(ConnectionString);
    }

    public Database(SqliteConnection Connection)
    {
        this.connection = Connection;
    }

    public static UsersDatabase User { get { return new UsersDatabase("Data Source=" + _LocalDatabasePath); } }

    #region Queries

    protected SqliteDataReader SelectQuery(string columns, string table, string condition)
    {
        if (this.Connected)
        {
            SqliteCommand cmd = this.connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + columns + " FROM " + table + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition) ? "" : " WHERE " + condition);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            return cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Inte ansluten till databasen");
        }
    }

    protected SqliteDataReader SelectQuery(string columns, string table)
    {
        return this.SelectQuery(columns, table, "");
    }
    protected void InsertQuery(string table, string columns, string values)
    {
        if (this.Connected)
        {
            SqliteCommand cmd = this.connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + columns + ") VALUES(" + values + ")";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Inte ansluten till databasen");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Connection
    public bool Connected
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.connection == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void Connect()
    {
        if (!this.Connected)
        {
            string db = _LocalDatabasePath;
            bool exists = File.Exists(db);
            if (!exists)
            {
                SqliteConnection.CreateFile(db);
            }
            this.connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + db);
            this.connection.Open();
        }
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        if (this.Connected)
        {
            this.connection.Close();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

}
```

UsersDatabase.cs:

```
public class UsersDatabase : Database
    {
public UsersDatabase(string connectionstring)
            : base(connectionstring)
        {
        }
        public UsersDatabase(SqliteConnection connection)
            : base(connection)
        {
    }

    public void CreateUser()
    {
        this.Connect();
        this.InsertQuery("People", "PersonID, FirstName, LastName", "'" + "namn11" + "', '" + "enamn11" + "'");
        this.Close();

    }

    public UserStruct[] GetAllUsers()
    {
        List<UserStruct> templist = new List<UserStruct>();

        this.Connect();
        SqliteDataReader reader = this.SelectQuery("*", "People", "");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            UserStruct tmpuser = new UserStruct();
            tmpuser.ID = reader["PersonID"].ToString();
            tmpuser.Name = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
            tmpuser.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
            templist.Add(tmpuser);
        }
        this.Close();

        return templist.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Activity1.cs:

```
[Activity(Label = "example_proj", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button btn2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn2);
            btn2.Click += new EventHandler(btn2_Click);

        }

        void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserStruct[] tmpusr = UsersDatabase.User.GetAllUsers();//get usrs
        }

    }
```

So... From the activity I call the UsersDatabase GetAllUsers() or CreateUser(). The UsersDatabase uses the Database class to help with the queries, and connections. So from the UsersDatabase I first call the Connect() method to establish connection to DB then I call for example the SelectQuery() to return a reader which I'm later gonna read in the UsersDatabase Class and fill a struct with info which is going to be returned to activity1.

As I said I get as far as returning the reader when I get the exception. The connection is open and the DB exists.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're getting? Also if you have a stacktrace that would be helpfull.

Comment: You are missing code that closes the datareader before closing the connection. Presumably your used SqlLite Adapter dislikes that. Always dispose objects (like the SqliteDataReader) that implement IDisposable when no longer used (with a using block for example).

Comment: Unhandled Exception:
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException:
Is evrything I get.


0x6D in example_proj.Database.SelectQuery at Database.cs:46

0x1E in example_proj.UsersDatabase.GetAllUsersRaw at UsersDatabase.cs:79

0x6 in example_proj.Activity1.btn2_Click at Activity1.cs:70

Comment: I just tried to put the Connect method inside Usersdatabase and removed the UsersDatabase : Database, I can then read without crash.
Why is that?